# How to customize Emacs key bindings for going to specific line / end of buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp, customization, text-editor, key-bindings

I want to customize Emacs so that pressing

<kbd>ESC :</kbd> `n` <kbd>RET</kbd>

takes me to line number `n`

and

<kbd>ESC :</kbd> `$` <kbd>RET</kbd>

takes me to the last line. (That's how the vi editor works.)

How can I achieve this inside my Emacs configuration file? Currently I have this in my `.emacs`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-9") 'prev-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-0") 'other-window)
```

I don't want to use any of the off-the-shelf solutions (eg. evil) because they are bloated and mess with my existing shortcuts.

Comment: Seriously question the wisdom of disabling the built-in behavior of M-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in a file and load it (load means execute):

```
(defun vi-goto-line (arg)
 (interactive "sLine:")
 (message arg)
 (if (string= "$" arg)
  (end-of-buffer)
  (goto-line (string-to-int arg))
 )
)

(global-set-key (kbd "M-:") 'vi-goto-line)
```

To load it you can use <kbd>M-x</kbd>`load-file` and then enter interactively the path to the file.

Keep in mind that the key combo <kbd>M-:</kbd> (which is the same as <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>) already has a meaning in Emacs, so this now gets cloaked.

Of course you also can load the file from your `.emacs` by putting `(load-file "/path/to/my/file")` into the `.emacs` or put these lines directly into your `.emacs` file (or any other configuration file which gets loaded)

Comment: Why would `M-x` get cloaked by the code you provide? OP wants to use `ESC :`, not `ESC x` :)

Comment: Ah, typo, yeah.  Of course, `M-:` would get cloaked!